# PHP Split html string into array

Tags: php, html, arrays, accordion, domdocument

I hope I can get some help from you guys.

This is what I'm struggling with,
I have a string of HTML that will look like this:

```
<h4>Some title here</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
(some other HTML here)

<h4>Some other title here</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
(some other HTML here)
```

I need to split all the `<h4>` from the rest of the content, but for example the content after the first `<h4>` and before the second `<h4>` needs to be related to the first `<h4>`, something like this:

```
Array {
       [0] => <h4>Some title here</h4>
       [1] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
}

Array {
       [0] => <h4>Some other title here</h4>
       [1] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
}
```

This is to build an accordion (quite difficult to explain why I'm doing this way, but it has to be this way), and the `<h4>` will be the accordion panel headings and when clicked it will expand and show the content associated with them.

I hope I made my problem clear, let me know of your thoughts and how should I do this the better way.

I was looking into `DOMDocument`, but I also tried with `explode()` but with no success.

I have this working with JavaScript but I need to achieve the same thing with PHP, but it's quite complicated to play with the DOM with PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `DOMDocument` can be a little hard, but it's not so bad.

Comment: Yes, it will always have h4 followed by any kind of HTML code, except h4, the only h4 are the titles. So yes I'm sure it will always be like that.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156164/parse-html-and-get-all-h3s-after-an-h2-before-the-next-h2-using-php

Comment: @DerekS thanks, this helped, going on the right track, just need to modify the code a bit to work like I wanted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted following the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156164/parse-html-and-get-all-h3s-after-an-h2-before-the-next-h2-using-php) that [Derek S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855126/derek-s) gave me.

This was the result:

```
$html_string = 'HTML string';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h4') as $node) {
   $title = $dom->saveHTML($node);
   $content[$title] = array();

   while(($node = $node->nextSibling) && $node->nodeName !== 'h4') {
      $content[$title] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
   }
}
```

This will save the titles inside `$title` and the correspondent content inside `$content[$title]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
preg_split("/<h4>.+</h4>/i", $html);
```

Comment: Your pattern is missing start- and enddelimeter. Beter to add the case insensitive tag as well

Comment: Oops! Must have been in a hurry... fixed!

Comment: Thank you @zack.lore 
I appreciate it, but found the solution with the previous code.

Comment: `preg_split` is definitely not the desired function to use here, `preg_match` is way more suitable. It took me over an hour to realize that `preg_split` actually removes all matches from the source, whereas what I (and the OP) needed was an array of all matches.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want -- though I'm sure there are other (and possibly better) ways

```
$aHTML = explode("<h4>", $cHTML);
foreach ($aHTML AS $nPos => $cPanel) {
  if ($nPos > 0) {
    $aPanel = explode("</h4>", $cPanel);
    $cHeader = "<h4>" . $aPanel[0] . "</h4>";
    $cPanelContent = $aPanel[1];
  }
}
```

It doesn't put it in the array format you stipulated -- though you could do that yourself inside the loop. Otherwise your content could be output/constructed inside the loop.

Edit: Added the h4 and /h4 back in for completeness

Comment: other ways is an regexp split on /<h4>.*</h4>/ for example

Comment: This won't work if your "h4" is actually "H4" (uppercase) or if you had a stray space (like "/h4 "). In other words, it works on good clean HTML that you can control.

Comment: i know, it was only a hint for other ways, but thanks for that ;)

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Sorry, that was a comment on my post -- not your post which I hadn't seen yet. I agree regexp split could work too.

Comment: ah well, but uppercase html tags are deprecated if im wrong?

Comment: I find that "deprecated" and "not used" are far too commonly not equal. If this processes the OPs own HTML code -- it should work. If they were trying to process something on another site (uncontrolled HTML) -- you have to rely that the coder on the other end doesn't do something that browsers would still allow -- deprecated or not. Just issuing the warning, it likely wouldn't be an issue to deal with.

Comment: I tried your code and I had to add a `=` in `if ($nPos > 0)` to become this `if ($nPos >= 0)` otherwise it wouldn't output anything. But even with that it only outputs the first `<h4>` followed by the content and then the second `<h4>` and stops there.

Comment: Thank you @DragonYen for your response and code, it helped, I have it almost working as I want it, but now I have to decide if it is better this way or with DOMDocument. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code with little small changes, And it will apply to all kinds of HTML not normal ones.

```
        $html_string = 'HTML string';
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html_string);

        $content = [];
        $value = '';

        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h4') as $node) {
           $title = $dom->saveHTML($node);
           $content[$k]['key'] = $title;

           while(($node = $node->nextSibling) && $node->nodeName !== 'h4') {
              $value .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
           }

           $content[$k]['value'] = $value;
        }
        
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($content);die;
```