# Filter html content by type of element in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Say I have a variable that contains html :

```
<?php 
$content = "<h3>Transition movement</h3><p>It's fun and will make you more resilient.</p>";
?>
```

Can I "filter" it so I can echo the title somewhere and the paragraph elsewhere, like below ?

```
<div class="big-purple"><?php echo $content_title; ?></div>
<div class="side-bar"><?php echo $content_paragraph; ?></div>
```

A bit like I would access DOM elements with javascript, only on server side before it's being loaded on the page. I'm asking this because I'm getting the content from a single rich text field in Wordpress, and I have to put the content in differents parts of my front-end layout.

Comment: PHP also has a DOM extension: http://php.net/dom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Split html string into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893753/php-split-html-string-into-array)

Comment: `DOMDocument` could help but only if your HTML is _valid_.

Comment: I ended up not using DOM because treyBake's answer was enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $content = '<h3>Transition movement</h3><p>It\'s fun and will make you more resilient.</p>';

    preg_match_all(
        '/\<\w[^<>]*?\>([^<>]+?\<\/\w+?\>)?|\<\/\w+?\>/i',
        $content,
        $matches
    );

    $html = $matches[0];

    $heading = $html[0];
    $p = $html[1];
?>

<div><?php echo $heading; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $p; ?></div>
```

the `preg_match` will match all the `< whatever html tag >` and break it into an array. It stores it in the first index (hence `$html = $matches[0]`) so just use that and then get the tags individually.

Potential bonus points for your pref.

```
function getHtmlTags($html)
{
    preg_match_all(
        '/\<\w[^<>]*?\>([^<>]+?\<\/\w+?\>)?|\<\/\w+?\>/i',
        $html,
        $matches
    );

    return $matches[0];
}

$html = getHtmlTags($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

How About

`$content = explode("</h3>", "<h3>Transition movement</h3><p>It's fun and will make you more resilient.</p>");//Split at end of h3`

And:

```
<div class="big-purple"><?php echo $content[0]; ?></div>
<div class="side-bar"><?php echo $content[1]; ?></div>
```

I dont recommend to code like this, but it works, if thats what you want.

Comment: if you don't recommend it - why suggest it?

Comment: Because it's in my opinion better to answer than to hold shout. And as long as it's working it ain't stupid, right?

Comment: I'd rather code that's most efficient and utilises PHP properly

Answer (score 0):

If I would like to do so, i would use more variables:

```
<?php 
   $headline = "<h3>Transition movement</h3>";
   $paragraph = "<p>It's fun and will make you more resilient.</p>";
   $fullContent = $headline . $paragraph;
?>
```

and later:

```
<div class="big-purple"><?php echo $headline; ?></div>
<div class="side-bar"><?php echo $paragraph; ?></div>
```

If you can't save it in two variables then split it before, but that is far less readable:

```
$content = explode("</h3>", "<h3>Transition movement</h3><p>It's fun and will make you more resilient.</p>");
```

Comment: I can't do this because I'm getting the whole html content in one string.